# Tooltip in navigation treeview

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation

I am new to sharepoint and currently using Sharepoint Foundation 2013. I created sites, subsites and multiple Document libraries in lower level subsite and enabled navigation treeview. I can see nice treeview as per my requirement.

Now, my requirement is to add Tooltip in each item (Document Libraries) and want to display 'Description' as a Tooltip. Currently it is displaying Document Library Name in a tooltip. Is there any trick to do it through Sharepoint Designer? I Cannot use Custom Webparts as of now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve this functionality.

To achieve this functionality you have to inject java script in SharePoint at site collection level and in java script you have to register navigation item hover event and you have to write JSOM code to fetch description and append it in tool tip.

Please visit this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56731/add-script-reference-to-all-pages-in-a-site-collection-when-a-feature-is-activat) how to inject java script, visit this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx) for how to get item property.